Retrieving data from Supabase [Flutter]
I have a created table with a movie_id field of type int8.(Supabase).
There is also a separate (in the application) variable (int) - movieid.
Ideally, the user_id should also be checked
I need to compare them, and if they are equal, then change the icon
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        actions: <Widget>[
          IconButton(
            icon: movieSupabase == movieid
                ? (Icons.favorite)
                : (Icons.favorite_border_outlined),
            onPressed: () async {
              await supabase.from('favorite').insert({'movie_id': movieid});
            },
          ),
        ],



:
I tried to connect streamBuilder but without success. I also tried to separately register a class for json
